# Java : Scroll Over JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing

I've got a vertically scrolling JPanel, on that JPanel are a couple of JScrollPanes, when the user scrolls down through the panel, if the users mouse goes over the JScrollPane they are no longer able to scroll the JPanel, the have to move their mouse off the JScrollPane and back onto the panel. It gets quite annoying after a while.

To this end is there any way to tell java to continue scrolling the parent JPanel unless the user clicks on the child JScrollPane and specifically tries to scroll it?
[image]

Comment: And what happens when they want to scroll the child scroll pane?  How do you manage the differences between the case?

Comment: Possibly on click, i was hoping someone would have an idea how i could implement it, or even better if somehow it can detect that the user is scrolling the parent so it should not start scrolling the child (just looking for ideas atm)

Comment: As I understand it, this functionality is likely controlled by the look and feel UI delegate

Comment: (+1) I got this problem once. but not able to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is [`JScrollPane#setWheelScrollingEnabled(boolean handleWheel)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setWheelScrollingEnabled%28boolean%29)